# Lightning Component JS - how to create a List of id on all checked checkboxes to send to Apex Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, html

When user clicks "Initiate Transfer" button, I need to create a List of id on all checked checkboxes. I'll pass this list as a param to Apex Controller like so:

```
sendData : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.sendData");
    action.setParams({
        "accountIds" : component.get("v.idList"),
    });
```

I've tried many things with JS so far, and I'm still not seeing a way to do this. pop, splice, filter do not seem optimal. Your help is appreciated.

[image]

The key line of html in question:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{!contract.id}" name="transferFromCheckbox" onclick="{!c.transferFromCheckboxOnclick}"/>
```

It's within an aura:iteration

```
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.compositeWrapper.contracts}" var="contract" indexVar="index">
                <tr scope="row" style="height: 1.4rem;">
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">{!index+1}</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">orderNumber</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">{!contract.contractType}</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">{!contract.startDay}</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">{!contract.endDay}</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">{!contract.creditsPurchased}</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">{!contract.creditsUsed}</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">{!contract.creditsTranferred}</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">{!contract.creditsExpired}</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">creditsRemaining</td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="{!contract.id}" name="transferFromCheckbox" 
                            onclick="{!c.transferFromCheckboxOnclick}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableBodyFormat slds-truncate">
                        <input type="radio" id="{!contract.id}" name="transferToRadioButton" onclick="{!c.transferToCheckboxOnclick}"/>
                    </td>          
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify an `aura:id`, and use `data-id` instead of `id`, which will become mangled during rendering.

```
<input aura:id="transferFromCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-id="{!contract.id}" name="transferFromCheckbox" 
                        onclick="{!c.transferFromCheckboxOnclick}"/>
```

And you can then get all the checked items easily (yes, using filter!):

```
var ids = cmp.find("transferFromCheckbox").filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked).map(input => input.dataset.id);
```

P.S. If you know you only have one item available, remember that SecureComponent.find will only return a single item instead of an Array, so you will need to check for that.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox! This looks great. I'm currently getting this error... $controller$transferButtonClick [n.split is not a function]
strange since I'm not explicitly using split anywhere in my code. (By the way, I removed onclick from the checkbox. I added your code to transferButtonClick )

Comment: Please see UPDATE in original post.